# Prove that $L\cap(M+N)=L\cap M+ L \cap N $ is not necessarily true for vector subspaces $L,M,N$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, vector-spaces

The above question is from [Finite-Dimensional Vector Spaces](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387900934) by Halmos.

This is my solution:

> $L\cap(M+N)=\{ a+b\>|\> a\in M\, \land\, b \in N\,\land a+b\in L\}$
>
> $L\cap M+L\cap N=\{a+b\>|\>a\in L \,\land a\in M\,\land b\in L\,\land\, b\in N                      \}$
>
> $\implies L\cap(M+N)=L\cap M+L\cap N\iff \\  (a\in M\, \land\, b \in N\,\land a+b\in L\iff a\in L \,\land a\in M\,\land b\in L\,\land\, b\in N) \iff \\
> (a+b\in L \iff a \in L\> \ \land\> b\in L )\iff \text{False}$

The last equivalency follows from [If sum of two vectors is in a subspace then the two vectors are also in the same subspace](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2055192/if-sum-of-two-vectors-is-in-a-subspace-then-the-two-vectors-are-also-in-the-same).

Question:

Is my proof airtight? How can I make it more compact and some alternative approach to solve this question would be welcome.

I am not interested in solutions which disproves the above by constructing a counter example like  [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/28241) rather an insight into the problem from a  general setting would be more insightful like the approach I used in my solution)

PS: I am not interested in alternative "proofs", I am more interested in the ways one can approach this problem and what are the consequences of this result which seems counter intuitive at a first glance.

Comment: For disproving a claim which says $\forall$, you have to show it's negation is true, so your so called proof has to be with $\exists$. Moreover for your last equivalency, aren't you using a counter example to claim that it is false?

Comment: It is not clear how you are proving that they are not equal. I would not eschew counterexamples from the perspective of providing insight. Three lines drawn through the origin in the place provides a pretty convincing insight to me.

Comment: @copper.hat It is false because if the sum of two vectors is in a subspace, it does not imply that the two vectors are in the same subspace

Comment: If you find what you wrote insightful that's all well and good, but you should be aware that to a lot of others it's going to be dense and hard to read (if not unsightly.)

Comment: @AnuragA Do you mean it should start with $\forall a,b ...$

Comment: @John: I understand that it is not true, I am just pointing out that if you are looking for insight, a counterexample works fine.

Comment: @John The only possible way you can claim $\iff False$ in your last line is if you have a counterexample. So basically you've written a lot of logical-symbol soup and you're still stuck with the task of finding a counterexample.

Comment: I think it's a very useful practice to attempt to prove things that aren't true and see what's missing. However, I wouldn't consider what you've written to be a "proof" really. Saying the last line is False isn't even possible without having an example for a case when this fails, so you're going to have to use counterexamples at some point regardless

Comment: @rschwieb That is a valid point, I shall keep that in mind in future

Comment: @John Here's another thing to consider: by writing a "proof" that something is not necessarily true, it has the appearance of (though it doesn't actually do that) proving that it's False for all $L, M, N$, which of course is not true. But rest assured that I see what you're doing in the exercise of writing everything out. I can tell  how it can be valuable.

Comment: Yes, so I will have to explicitly prove that at least one combination of $l,M,N$ exists for which it is false?

Comment: Yes. You have to find $L,M,N$ that don't satisfy the equality. If your proof were correct then the equality would fail for all $L,M,N.$ Obviously if $L=M=N$ the equality holds.

Comment: Is a better idea to ask such questions in chat once I get sufficient reputation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is not true that $L\cap(M+N)\ne (L\cap M)+(L\cap N)$ for all subspaces.

For instance, if $L=V$ (the vector space we're dealing with), the equality $L\cap(M+N)=(L\cap M)+(L\cap N)$ is obvious.

The equality also holds for $L=\{0\}$ or for $L=M=N$.

So you can't make your “proof” more compact: it isn't a proof to begin with.

Comment: Can it be converted into a proof by using quantifiers?

Comment: @John A proof of what? There exists a vector space such that three of its subspaces $L,M,N$ don't satisfy $L\cap(M+N)=L\cap M+L\cap N$. What else?

Comment: yes, that is what I meant

Comment: @John A counterexample is what you need. It can be given in any space with dimension at least $2$ (or infinite, of course).